hardware restricted password entry
Is there any way that you can restrict password prompts to accept input from only one device? If I were to have an extra keyboard hooked up can it be setup to be interpreted differently? Also I suppose along the same lines do they have something for this to have different language keyboards hooked up at the same time?

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Your question is not answerable in it's current form. Which OS and version are you using? Is this a laptop, desktop, or server? What kind of keyboard does it have, wired, wireless, Bluetooth? Edit your question and add all these information.
